# C++ templates - why types come first, and integer parameters after

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

For example, in Stroustrup's matrix implementation, why the type of elements comes first, and then comes the number of dimensions? Also, in all std classes, this rule is obeyed: in the template parameter lists between the <>, first come the types, and then actual int values.

Comment: Usually, it doesn't matter, it is a personal preference/following a code standard.

Comment: It is not a strong rule, in your own classes you may choose an order of parameters which you want. And what `std` classes do you mean?

Comment: If, by `std` classes, you mean e.g. [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant), the order matters in that case, because the first template parameter determines the type of the remaining non-type parameter(s). Otherwise, order is a matter of choice.

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing this? Is it a commonly accepted practice? Does it make template specialization any easier?

Comment: Well, e.g. [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/type/sequence.hpp), a `template <typename T, size_t... N> using array = ...` is defined, where `array<T,N>` is like `std::array<T,N>` (fixed number of elements), `array<T>` is like `vector<T>` (dynamic), and `array<T,N1,N2,N3>` is 3-dimensional. So this kind of ordering is convenient here. Otherwise, I don't see any real "advantage".